# How to validate an input string with few fields in the enum

Tags: java, enums

I have my below enum -

```
public enum TestEnum {
    h1, h2, h3, h4;

    public static String forCode(int code) {
    return (code >= 0 && code < values().length) ? values()[code].name() : null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TestEnum.h1.name());
        String ss = "h3";

        try {
           TestEnum.valueOf(ss); // but this validates with all the enum values
           System.out.println("valid");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
           System.out.println("invalid");
        }           
    }
}
```

I need to compare string `ss` only with `h1` , `h2` or `h4` in the enum..

Meaning if h3 is being passed as a string, I would like to return false or throw `IllegalArgumntException`.

I won't need to validate `ss` with `h3` in the enum.. How would I do this using the enum?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is more elegant solution but as for now I would solve it this way:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public enum TestEnum {
    h1, h2, h3, h4;

    public static boolean checkExcept(String el, TestEnum... except){
        boolean results = false;
        try{
            results = !Arrays.asList(except).contains(TestEnum.valueOf(el));
        }catch (Exception e){}
        return results;
    }

    public static String forCode(int code) {
        return (code >= 0 && code < values().length) ? values()[code].name() : null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String ss = "h3";

        if(TestEnum.checkExcept(ss,TestEnum.h1, TestEnum.h2, TestEnum.h3)){
           System.out.println("valid");
        }else{
           System.out.println("invalid");
        }

        ss = "h1";

        if(TestEnum.checkExcept(ss,TestEnum.h2)){
           System.out.println("valid");
        }else{
           System.out.println("invalid");
        }

        ss = "h2";

        if(TestEnum.checkExcept(ss,TestEnum.h2)){
            System.out.println("valid");
        }else{
            System.out.println("invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

PS: You can implement `checkOnly` to use whitelist instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate like this:

```
 ss.equals("h3")
```

or in a more convoluted way:

```
ss.equals(h3.toString())
```